# wordpress + jquery syntax error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, syntax, syntax-error

I got this code here...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        alert($('.thickbox'));
    });
</script>
```

and I put this code in my wordpress theme footer.php file at the bottom. When I went to my page, the alert did not appear, I check my error console and found this error

```
TypeError: $ is not a function  

$('document').ready(function() {
```

what gives? my jquery file is in the header, so this should work...or is there a specfic way to put jquery in wordpress?

Comment: If you're including jQuery *after* that line of script, it won't work as script tags are processed inline.

Comment: Nope, I am including jQuery first and then that line of code, should work

Comment: Ahhh man, someone put a link on here and I was totally about to click on it and then bam gone :(

Comment: Ah, in that case it's probably what JKirchartz suggested..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wordpress's packaged jQuery defaults to [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, use `jQuery('document')`, or wrap your code like

```
(function($) { 
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
})(jQuery);
```

or in your document ready like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Comment: thanks JKirchartz...it worked but you have an extra `(` at the top

Answer (score 1):

try jQuery instead of $

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
    alert($('.thickbox'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

'$' is just an alias for 'jQuery'. if `$('document')` isn't working, try `jQuery('document')`